# Unable to detect web context for ionic app when using new chrome (v 83)

Tags: android, google-chrome, ionic-framework, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

Im trying to run dev tools using chrome for hybrid mobile app built in ionic, it was working completely fine and i was able to inspect html element but after chrome update to 83, the app is not detected in order can inspect the element as shown below

[image]

Comment: Chrome regularly breaks compatibility with older versions of mobile Chrome. Try updating it and also switch the system's webview to Chrome if it's not already set.

Comment: @wOxxOm both emulator and desktop chrome are on latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bug with google chrome to be fixed with upcoming updates